# Backbone event doesn't always happen on `el`

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm working on my own version of a Backbone [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/#/) App. Here's my [code](https://github.com/adamzerner/bbtodos/tree/iteration5-todomvc-style) so far.

---

> The Backbone events hash allows us to attach event listeners to either el-relative custom selectors, **or directly to el if no selector is provided**. An event takes the form of a key-value pair 'eventName selector': 'callbackFunction' and a number of DOM event-types are supported, including click, submit, mouseover, dblclick and more.
>
> http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

`'dblclick': 'showEdit'` doesn't seem to be happening on `el` for me.

When I double click somewhere in the inner `.view-mode` div, `$(e.target)` is that `.view-mode` div.

[image: clicking on .view-mode]

But when I click outside of `.view-mode` but inside of the `li`, `$(e.taret)` is what it should be.

[image: clicking outside of .view-mode but inside of the li]

Why is this?

---

Code:

**todo.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  className: 'list-group-item',

  template: _.template( $('#todo-template').html() ),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
    this.$el.find('.edit-mode').hide();
    this.$el.find('.remove-todo').hide();
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    'click input[type="checkbox"]': 'check',
    'mouseenter': 'showRemove',
    'mouseleave': 'hideRemove',
    'click .remove-todo': 'remove',
    'dblclick': 'makeEditable'
  },

  check: function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).data('id');
    var model = app.todos.get(id);
    model.save({
      completed: true
    });
  },

  showRemove: function(e) {
    $(e.target).find('.remove-todo').show();
  },

  hideRemove: function(e) {
    $(e.target).find('.remove-todo').hide();
  },

  remove: function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    var id = $(e.target).data('id');
    var model = app.todos.get(id);
    model.destroy({
      success: function(model) {
        app.todos.remove(model);
        $el.closest('li').remove();
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Unable to remove todo.');
      }
    });
  },

  makeEditable: function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).html());
    $(e.target).find('.view-mode').hide();
    $(e.target).find('.edit-mode').show();
  }
});
```

**todo template**

```
<script type='text/template' id='todo-template'>
  <div class='view-mode'>
    <input 
      type='checkbox'
      data-id='<%= id %>'
      <% if (completed) { %>checked<% } %>
    >
    <%= title %>
    <a data-bypass class='remove-todo' data-id='<%= id %>'>&times;</a>
  </div>
  <div class='edit-mode'>
    <p>Edit Mode</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` refers to the node on which the event occurred. [Event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) means this may be descendent of the node that your handler is attached to.

To get the node that the event handler is attached to, use `e.currentTarget`.

See [`Event.currentTarget` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).